# Unable to calculate total in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm creating an simple shopping cart application, When user adding multiple quantity of same product. I'm unable to calculate the total.

Below is my logic,

Product Data structure,

```
product = {
      'productName': 'Sample Product',
      'productImage': productImage,
      'rate': 100,
      'quantity': 1
    }

this.addToCartService.cartItems.subscribe(product => {
  if (product) {
    const productExistInCart = this.cartItems.find(({ productName }) => productName === product.productName);
    if (!productExistInCart) {
      this.cartItems.push(product);
      return;
    } else {
      productExistInCart.quantity++
    }
    this.totalPrice = this.cartItems
      .map(item => item.rate)
      .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cart_box dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show">
    <ul class="cart_list" *ngIf="cartItems.length">
      <li *ngFor="let cartItem of cartItems; let i = index">
        <a (click)="removeFromCart(i)" class="item_remove"><i class="ion-close"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="{{cartItem.productImage}}" alt="cart_thumb1">{{cartItem.productName}}</a>
        <span class="cart_quantity"> {{cartItem.quantity}} x <span class="cart_amount"> <span
              class="price_symbole">₹</span>{{cartItem.rate}}</span></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cart_footer">
      <p class="cart_total">Total: <span class="cart_amount"> <span
            class="price_symbole">₹</span>{{totalPrice}}</span>
      </p>
      <p class="cart_buttons"><a href="cart.html" class="btn btn-default btn-radius view-cart">View Cart</a><a
          href="checkout.html" class="btn btn-dark btn-radius checkout">Checkout</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm stuck here, I don't know how to update the total of exiting items. Please help.

**Curent output is**

[image]

As per the above picture, total should be of 400. but it is displaying as 100.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to be able to know what's wrong. What form does an element in `this.cartItems` take? Are you using any npm packages for your service, or have you made it yourself?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: In `this.totalPrice = this.cartItems
      .map(item => item.rate)
      .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);` where are you taking quantity in account?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi, That is the challenge i'm dono how to take the updated quantity for calculating the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not taking `quantity` into account while calculating the total price. To fix this, try this :

```
        this.totalPrice = (this.cartItems
          .map(item => item.rate* item.quantity)
          .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0));
```